# I cannot get accuracy score to match when measured before and after assigning to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, xgboost

I am working on a classifier which will use non-nan values from `Target_Column` to predict what should be in the place of all nan values. But after training my model, I test it before and after assigning the predictions to a new column in my original dataframe. These two tests do not match. To me, the issue appears to be that one of the transformations after prediction is somehow shuffling the predictions so that they no longer match. I have removed as much extraneous code as I can.

```
##############################################################
### Here is the initial data transformation for background ###
###       You can skip to next section for now...          ###
##############################################################

df = pd.read_excel('./Data/[Excel File That Holds Data].xlsx')
df['Target_Column'] = df['Target_Column'].astype('str').str.strip()
le = LabelEncoder()
y_full = le_sub_system.fit_transform(df['Target_Column'].astype('str').str.strip())

desc_vec = TfidfVectorizer(ngram_range=(1,3), max_features=1000)
tag_vec = TfidfVectorizer(ngram_range=(1,4), analyzer='char', max_features=1000)

desc = desc_vec.fit_transform(df.descriptor.astype('str').fillna(''))
tag = tag_vec.fit_transform(df.tag.astype('str').fillna(''))

X = scipy.sparse.hstack([desc, tag])

### The indexing here matches the indexing done in the line marked below ###
nan_encoding = le.transform(['nan'])[0]
X_train = X.todense()[y_full != nan_encoding]
y_train = y_full[y_full != nan_encoding]

X_train.shape, y_train.shape #---> ((94669, 2000), (94669,))

########################################
### Here is where the problem starts ###
########################################

clf = xgb.XGBClassifier(n_estimators=10, max_depth=11, tree_method='gpu_hist', n_jobs=94)
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

out_full = clf.predict(X)
out_training_set = clf.predict(X_train)
df['Target_Predicted'] = le.inverse_transform(out_full)

>>> accuracy_score(out_training_set, y_train) 
0.9832152024421933

### The indexing here matches the indexing done in the lines marked above ###
>>> print(accuracy_score(df.Target_Column[y_full != nan_encoding], df.Target_Predicted[y_full != nan_encoding]))
0.0846422799438042

>>> print(accuracy_score(df.Target_Column[(df.Target_Column != 'nan')], df.Target_Predicted[(df.Target_Column!= 'nan')]))
0.0846422799438042

>>> (df.Target_Column[(df.Target_Column!= 'nan')].values == le.inverse_transform(y_train)).all()
True

>>> (df.Target_Column[y_full != nan_encoding] == le.inverse_transform(y_train)).all()
True

>>> (le.transform(df.Target_Predicted[y_full != nan_encoding]) == out[y_full != nan_encoding]).all()
True
```

As you can see, both ways of indexing the newly created columns in the dataframe return the same results, and they are indexed exactly the same way as when I created the training set initially, and (for the actual target values) returns exactly the same values. So how can the accuracy have changed?

Comment: Highly difficult to understand your problem based on the question, but I try to find out. Anyway: out is from predicts with X, scores are from predicts with X_dense. Is it correct?

Comment: @Geeocode yes, `out` is predicted from `X`, and I score from `X_dense`, but I then assign `out` to a new column in `df`, and when I use `classification_report` I index in exactly the same way as I used to create `X_dense` (verified in the last 3 lines). Apologies that it is confusing, I couldn't think of anything I could remove that would make it more clear without losing important info.

Comment: @Geeocode I have also changed the question to hopefully remove some confusion.

Comment: I just arrived and looked back to see if you still need help, as I see that meantime my comment helped others to recognize the main problem, as I my question suggested. So I am glad , if you managed to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think it might be related to the fact that you are using predict on a sparse matrix (or maybe there's some shuffling like you suggested). Anyhoo, try just filling the prediction column with nans (or any value you need to represent the missing values) and then fill the indexes for which you have the target variable with the predictions from the dense dataframe:

```
tmp = pd.Series(y_full)
valid_indexes = tmp[tmp!=nan_encoding].index.values
df['Target_Predicted'] = le.inverse_transform(nan_encoding)
df.Target_Predicted.iloc[valid_indexes ,] = le.inverse_transform(out_training_set)
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Unbelievable - I never once considered that predicting on a sparse matrix would cause this kind of headache. This answer led me to try adding X.todense() within the predict line and that worked - one line fix.

Comment: Well, you can't technically know how (or even if) sparse matrix are accepted by the model. Xgboost original interface only accepts DMatrix also for this reason - avoids confusions of this type. Glad it helped though!

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies with predicting on a sparse matrix, as Davide DN suggested in his answer. Changing the line

`out_full = clf.predict(X)`

to

`out_full = clf.predict(X.todense())`

solved the problem immediately. Hopefully if someone else has the same problem, then their data fits in memory in dense format.